# How to retrieve input parameters?

Tags: vbscript, wsh

I have two scripts: `One.vbs` and `Email.vbs`.

`One.vbs` is calling `Email.vbs` with an argument `reportFile` (String) as below.

```
Dim objShell
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run "email.vbs" , reportFile
```

When I try retrieving the argument in `Email.vbs` as

```
' == Read the Argument
fileName = WScript.Arguments.Item(0)
```

I'm getting the error

> Subscript out of range

with error code 800A0009.

I have tried Googling a lot on this but nothing seem working as expected. Just want to know if I'm doing it right, if not what is the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the second argument to `objShell.Run` is `intWindowStyle` (see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/d5fk67ky%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)):

> Optional. Integer value indicating the appearance of the program's
>   window. Note that not all programs make use of this information.

Try this instead, i.e. without the comma:

```
objShell.Run "email.vbs " & reportFile
```

Comment: Did you copy and paste what I gave you?  Mess around with it; it works.  I've written literally hundreds of VB scripts that do this.

Comment: @Vishwa You may need to add quotes around `reportFile` if the string contains spaces: `"email.vbs """ & reportFile & """"`

Comment: @roryap Thanks you for this. I found the cause. I had declared the string `reportFile` inside a function and it was not accessible outside. I have moved it out and it worked..   Just to sum up - the parameters that we are passing must be string and by default the first word (string) is the script name and each word is an argument ( arguments1, argument2 ... ), am I correct in understanding this? Please correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: Yes you are correct, but make sure you heed  Ansgar Wiechers' advice to enclose any arguments which themselves contain spaces within quotes.